# how i can get and render sprite form dataPath?

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite

Sprite SpriteModding(string path)

```
{
    byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(Application.dataPath + "/Resources/fgsoftwarestudio.png");
            Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(512, 512, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
            texture.filterMode = FilterMode.Trilinear;
            texture.LoadImage(bytes);
            Sprite sprite = Sprite.Create(texture, new Rect(0, 0, 512, 512), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.0f), 1.0f);

            sprite_bg.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = sprite;
            
            return null;

}
```

`
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pa8nr.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pa8nr.png)

[image: on data path]

[image: on game]

i open game and sprite don't render

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are loading a file from resources folder try `Resources.Load` more information here: [Information about Resources folder](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html)